# How to perfectly make developer products in roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox, marketplace

I have been learning to make roblox games, but recently I got an issue where the code is correct but the thing doesn't work.
I am doing as per this [roblox website](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Developer-Products-In-Game-Purchases).

But even when i do the similar kind of thing it doesn't work. Can anyone correct me where I'm going wrong?

```lua
local MarketPlaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local donateEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("donateEvent")

local ProductFunctions = {}

ProductFunctions[1249752191] = function(Player)
    donateEvent:FireClient(Player)
end
ProductFunctions[1249752535] = function(Player)
    donateEvent:FireClient(Player)
end
ProductFunctions[1249752534] = function(Player)
    donateEvent:FireClient(Player)
end
ProductFunctions[1249752537] = function(Player)
    donateEvent:FireClient(Player)
end
ProductFunctions[1249752533] = function(Player)
    donateEvent:FireClient(Player)
end
ProductFunctions[1249752530] = function(Player)
    donateEvent:FireClient(Player)
end
ProductFunctions[1249752532] = function(Player)
    donateEvent:FireClient(Player)
end
ProductFunctions[1249752536] = function(Player)
    donateEvent:FireClient(Player)
end
ProductFunctions[1249752531] = function(Player)
    donateEvent:FireClient(Player)
end

MarketPlaceService.ProcessReceipt = function(info)
    local Player = Players:GetPlayerByUserId(info.PlayerId)
    local Product = info.PurchaseId

    if not Player then
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    end

    local success, err = pcall(ProductFunctions[Product],Player)
    if not success then
        warn('error')
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    end

    return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
end
```

My problem here is that even though the process receipt is there and the ID exactly  matches with the given values to be checked. The event inside the function doesn't fire at all! Not even 1 event is fired in all of them...

Comment: What type of script are you using? Local or Server?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say it isn't working correctly? It looks like all of your developer products are doing the same thing. Is that intentional? What isn't working?

Comment: @CrannMoroney, I'm using a server Script

Comment: @Kylaaa, i know that was intentional to check if any of them atleast works. But the problem here is that the event doesn't fire itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was that i wrote

```lua
local Product = info.PurchaseId
```

It should actually be

```lua
local Product = info.ProductId
```